# 301 Redirect GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect a url like this:

http://originalwebsite.com/event/detail.html?id=13

to

http://newwebsite.com/events

I've tried the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
redirect 301 /event/detail.html?id=13 /events
```

but it's not working...

I've also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /event/detail.html?id=13
RewriteRule (.*) /events [R=301,L]
```

Could anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong? It's a pretty bog standard redirect...

the `GET` parameter is not required to be passed through, I just want to point old page at new page.

Many thanks

After some further investigation I've discovered that you cannot pass variables in the `Redirect` so I've alterthed the code to the below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=13$
RewriteRule (.*) /events? [L,R=301]
```

This is working however the issue I am having is that this redirect applies to any URL with `id=13` appended to it. I need to be more specific as I want to redirect /event/detail.html?id=13 to /events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(.*)** is a catch-all pattern, so if you the rule to be applied for a specific uri only,You can match against that uri in RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=13$
RewriteRule ^event/detail\.html$ /events? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for that it worked perfectly. To clarify my above code was working but because I used `(.*)` it would have been matching the redirect to all URLs is that correct?